# Why is my range-based for loop working for some data types but not others?

Tags: c++, iterator, char, stdvector, range-based-loop

I tried out some range-based for loops to get an idea of the concept and for arrays and vectors of integers, it works fine. But for a vector of characters, my compiler does not give any error messages or the desired result, just a line of red dots. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<char> myVector {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    myVector.push_back('e');
    for (auto i : myVector){
        cout << myVector[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What’s wrong? I can’t find anything. When I substitute integers for characters, it works fine.

Comment: I think you meant `cout << i << endl;` It would be less confusing if you named your variable `c`.

Comment: `i` contains one of the elements of the vector of type `char`. So using it as an index is addressing a value way out of bounds.

Comment: `i` IS the value in `myVector`, not an index to be used to get the value in `myVector`

Comment: In each iteration of your loop, `i` is a copy of the value of an element of `myVector`.   To print that element, do `cout << i << endl;`    Your loop, as is, gives undefined behaviour since `'a'`, `'b'`, etc all have numeric values greater than 6, so you are accessing non-existent elements of `myVector`.   If your approach works for an array of `int`, you're just getting lucky (e.g. you've chosen elements of the array that are all between `0` and `myVector.size()-1`).

Answer (score 6):

In this loop:

```
for (auto i : myVector){
    cout << myVector[i] << endl;
}
```

The variable `i` has the type `char`. It is a copy of each element stored in the vector. So, to output the elements of the vector, you need to write:

```
for (auto i : myVector){
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Without diving into details, you may imagine this range-based for loop like this:

```
for ( auto first = myVector.begin(), last = myVector.end(); first != last; ++first )
{
    auto i = *first;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Pay attention to that in C++ 20 the construction of the range-based for loop was enlarged. For example you may write

```
for ( size_t j = 0; auto i : myVector){
    std::cout << j++ << ": " << i << std::endl;
}
```

In this case the program output will be

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Describing it like a normal for loop with pointers helped me visualize it better. :)